(missing buildfscript{ } ). Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of metadata 1.9.0,expected version 1.7.1
Here the debug console gives a way to fixed the problem to change
ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>
so i tried to change the latest kotlin version,as i see the ohter solution
the line ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>   include in buildscript{ ... }
 buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.23' // Change here
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
       // classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

But in my project level build.gridle don't have any buildscript{..}
 build.gradle (my project)
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

therefore i tried another solution where i changed the version in plugin of  settings.gradle
settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.22" apply false 
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.1" apply false
}

after that the debug console and device screen - debug console and device
Can you help me with a solution?

Where are the values.xml file located and what are its contents? Did you define FirebaseOptions correctly?

Check this link
